# Berry curvature flux around a Weyl node

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-phase, weyl-semimetal

How can I formally show (or at least argue) that, given the crystal Hamiltonian expansion around a Weyl node in a three-dimensional Brillouin Zone located at $\vec{k}_{0}$,

$\hat{H}=f_{0}(\vec{k}_{0})\mathbb{I}+\vec{v}_{0}\cdot\vec{q}\mathbb{I}+\sum_{a=x,y,z}\vec{v}_{a}\cdot\vec{q}\sigma^{a}$

with $\vec{k}=\vec{k}_{0}+\vec{q}$, the Berry flux through a sphere surrounding $\vec{k}_{0}$ corresponds to the one of a sink or source of Berry curvature, depending on the chirality of the Weyl node, defined as $\chi=\vec{v}_{x}\cdot(\vec{v}_y\times\vec{v}_z)$?

Comment: Where does this question come from? What do you know about Berry phases already? What difficulty do you have in applying the general notion of Berry phase/curvature/flux to this specific situation?

Comment: @ACuriousMind the calculation is huge and I don't think that's what my homework expects me to do so either I am missing some simplification or this can be argued in some way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Weyl points ($K$, $q = 0$), we can approximate a tight-binding Hamiltonian  as
\begin{equation}
H(\vec{K}+\vec{q})=  v \vec{q} \cdot \vec{\sigma}.
\end{equation}
As this is a general $2x2$ Hamiltonian, we know that the eigenvalues will be of the form $ v|q|$. \
\end{definition}
The corresponding eigenvectors are given as
\begin{equation} |- \rangle =  \biggl(\begin{array}{c}
     e^{-i \varphi} \sin \theta /2  \\
    - \cos \theta /2
\end{array}\biggr), \ |+ \rangle = \biggl(
    \begin{array}{c}
    e^{-i \varphi} \cos \theta /2   \\
   \sin \theta /2 
\end{array}\biggr)
\end{equation}

Note that these are not well-defined (single valued) at $\theta = \pi$. We can define a $U(1)$gauge transformation so that the eigenvectors are
\begin{equation} |- \rangle =  \biggl(\begin{array}{c}
     \sin \theta /2  \\
    - e^{i \varphi}\cos \theta /2
\end{array}\biggr), \ |+ \rangle = \biggl(
    \begin{array}{c}
    \cos \theta /2  \\
    e^{i \varphi}\sin \theta /2 
\end{array}\biggr)
\end{equation}
Now these are single valued except at the north-pole $\theta = 0$.
\
We can compute the Berry curvature in both gauges
\begin{gather}
    A_\theta = i \langle - | \partial_\theta | - \rangle = 0 \\
     A_\phi = i \langle - | \partial_\phi | - \rangle = (\sin \theta /2)^2 \\
\end{gather}
and
\begin{gather}
    A_\theta = i \langle - | \partial_\theta | - \rangle = 0 \\
     A_\phi = i \langle - | \partial_\phi | - \rangle = - (\cos \theta /2)^2 \\
\end{gather}

From here you can see that this is no longer single valued at $\theta = 0$. This requires that we define a new gauge so that
\begin{gather}
    A_\theta = i \langle - | \partial_\theta | - \rangle = 0 \\
     A_\phi = i \langle - | \partial_\phi | - \rangle = - (\cos \theta /2)^2 \\
\end{gather}
However, both of these give the gauge independent
\begin{equation}
    F_{ \theta \phi} = \partial_\theta A_\phi - \partial_\phi A_\theta = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{2}
\end{equation}
Since we just have $q\cdot \sigma$, our angles are just spherical coordinate parameterization. Now we can write the Berry curvature in terms of the inverse Jacobian
\begin{equation}
    F_{q_i,q_j} = F_{\theta, \phi} \frac{\partial(\theta ,\phi)}{\partial(q_i,q_j)} = \frac{\sin}{2}\frac{\partial(\theta, \phi)}{\partial(q_i,q_j)} = \frac{1}{2|q|^2}
\end{equation}
Now the field strength pseudovector is given by
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{F}_i = \epsilon_{ijk}F_{jk}
\end{equation}
and so we have
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{F} = \frac{-\vec{q}}{2 |q|^3}
\end{equation}
From here it is clear that we can use Gauss's theorem
\begin{equation}
\int_{\text {sphere }} \mathcal{F}(q) \cdot d \mathbf{S}= 2 \pi \int  d \theta \ d \phi \ \sin (\theta) =- 2 \pi (1)
\end{equation}
which gives a quantized Berry curvature given by the Chern number $C = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \gamma$

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the maths, let us set the zero of energy at the crossing point and make the velocity isotropic (essentially re-scale your definition of $\mathbf{q}$), so that the Hamiltonian around the Weyl point becomes:
$$
\hat{H}(\mathbf{q})=v_{\mathrm{F}}\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{\sigma}=v_{\mathrm{F}}(q_1\sigma_1+q_2\sigma_2+q_3\sigma_3),
$$
for $\mathbf{q}=(q_1,q_2,q_3)$. The $i$th component of the Berry curvature is:
$$
\Omega_i(\mathbf{q})=-\frac{1}{8\pi}\frac{1}{|\mathbf{q}|^3}\varepsilon_{ijk}\mathbf{q}\cdot\partial_{q_j}\mathbf{q}\times\partial_{q_k}\mathbf{q}.
$$
If you carry out the calculation for all three components, and combine them into a vector $\Omega=(\Omega_1,\Omega_2,\Omega_3)$, you get:
$$
\Omega(\mathbf{q})=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\mathbf{q}}{|\mathbf{q}|^3}.
$$
The flux over a sphere S of fixed radius $|\mathbf{q}|$ is $\Omega(\mathbf{q})\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\Omega(\mathbf{q})\cdot\hat{\mathbf{q}}dS$. The surface element is $dS=q^2\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$ (where I use $(q,\theta,\phi)$ as my spherical coordinates for $\mathbf{q})$, so that $\Omega(\mathbf{q})\cdot d\mathbf{S}=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$, and the integral now becomes very simple:
$$
\int_{\mathrm{sphere}}\Omega(\mathbf{q})\cdot d\mathbf{S}=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\sin(\theta)d\theta\int d\phi=-1,
$$
and this corresponds to a left-handed Weyl point. If you repeat the same analysis for the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}(\mathbf{q})=-v_{\mathrm{F}}\mathbf{q}\cdot\sigma$, then you get the Berry curvature as:
$$
\Omega(\mathbf{q})=+\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\mathbf{q}}{|\mathbf{q}|^3},
$$
and the integral over the flux gives you $+1$, corresponding to a right-handed Weyl point.

Comment: So you are assuming $\vec{v}_{a}=v_{F}\hat{e}_{a}$? Then how can I get to the chirality definition I gave in the question? And where can I find a detailed derivation for the Berry curvature formula below?

Comment: I have taken the velocity to be isotropic to simplify the maths. But this can be done without loss of generality, simply think of it as a "re-scaling" of the coordinates $\mathbf{q}$

Comment: As to the definition of the Berry curvature, in 3D you can write it down as a vector as I did, and then it is given by $\Omega=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is the Berry connection. If you are asking about more general background about these, David Vanderbilt's book "Berry phases in Electronic Structure Theory" is a good starting point.

Comment: How should I proceed without the assumptions you took in order to derive a result for the Chern number which actually depends on the determinant definition of the chirality I gave rather than making the case distinction for positive and negative chirality as in your answer?

Comment: I think they are equivalent. In your case, you have $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{q}$, and when you calculate this quantity with your specific values for $\mathbf{v}$ you will get either the Hamiltonian I wrote with $+v_{\mathrm{F}}$ or the one with $-v_{\mathrm{F}}$. Then the answer will proceed as mine.

Comment: I don't think they're exactly equivalent as I have 3 velocities

Comment: But you are still in 3D, so there are really only three-dimensional vectors. Note that when you calculate $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{q}$ for each of your three velocities, then you sum over them, so you will still get something that you will be able to write as $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{q}$ for a "single" velocity.

Comment: The formula you give for the chirality is incorrect. It should be  $\chi= {\bf v}_x\cdot({\bf v}_y\times {\bf v}_z)/ |{\bf v}_x\cdot({\bf v}_y\times {\bf v}_z)|$.  This is $\pm 1$, while your definion is not an integer in general.  The Berry flux is $2\pi \chi$.  The flux is a topological invariant so you can take the ${bf v}_i$ to orthonormal without changing the flux.

Comment: @mikestone yes you're right I forgot the sgn in the definition. Do you have any ideas about the derivation of the flux with the definition of $\chi$ you gave?

Comment: In order to compute the Berry curvature from the connection, I would naively expect that you need to compute the eigenvectors. It seems here that your eigenvector is $\vec{q}$ but that does not make sense?

Comment: @AndrewHardy both expressions I give for the Berry curvature are expressions for the Berry curvature, equivalent to the expression for F in your answer (indeed, my second expression is the same as yours up to a constant). The Berry curvature is a function of the wave vector q in reciprocal space.